# Error creating rule engine Drools

Tags: rule-engine, swrlapi

```
Exception in thread "main" org.swrlapi.exceptions.SWRLRuleEngineException: Error creating rule engine Drools. Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError. Message: org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager.getIRIMappers()Lorg/semanticweb/owlapi/util/PriorityCollection;
at org.swrlapi.factory.DefaultSWRLRuleAndQueryEngineFactory.createSWRLRuleEngine(DefaultSWRLRuleAndQueryEngineFactory.java:71)
at org.swrlapi.factory.DefaultSWRLRuleAndQueryEngineFactory.createSWRLRuleEngine(DefaultSWRLRuleAndQueryEngineFactory.java:41)
at org.swrlapi.factory.SWRLAPIFactory.createSWRLRuleEngine(SWRLAPIFactory.java:38)
at swrlagaintest.plzwork.runWithOWLAPI(plzwork.java:30)
at swrlagaintest.plzwork.main(plzwork.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager.getIRIMappers()Lorg/semanticweb/owlapi/util/PriorityCollection;
    at org.swrlapi.factory.DefaultSWRLAPIOWLOntology.addSWRLAPIOntologies(DefaultSWRLAPIOWLOntology.java:1469)
    at org.swrlapi.factory.DefaultSWRLAPIOWLOntology.<init>(DefaultSWRLAPIOWLOntology.java:161)
    at org.swrlapi.factory.SWRLAPIInternalFactory.createSWRLAPIOntology(SWRLAPIInternalFactory.java:266)
    at org.swrlapi.factory.DefaultSWRLRuleAndQueryEngineFactory.createSWRLRuleEngine(DefaultSWRLRuleAndQueryEngineFactory.java:53)
    ... 4 more
```

am trying to create a SWRL rule engine using the SWRLAPI just for testing but i got this error.

Comment: Can you please specify the rule that creates the error?

Comment: i used a random rule in protege (btw i use protege 5.2) 
light (?l) ^ Enabled (?l, false) -> Enabled (?l, true)

Comment: and i don't think it's in the rule cause i think SWRLAPIFactory is the problem